# User "elif" in "for" loop with nunjucks

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, nunjucks

Basically I try to combine multiple conditions in a for loop. For two conditions its working fine

`{% for blockName in (userblocks if sitename == "user" else xpertBlocks) %}`

but is there also a way, to realize three or more conditions in a for loop, like so:

`{% for blockName in (userBlocks if sitename == "user" elif sitename == "xpert" xpertBlocks else "provider") %}`

I couldn't find anything in the nunjucks documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% set chooser = {user: userBlocks, xpert: xpertBlocks, ...} %}
{% set blocks = chooser[sitename] or providerBlocks %}

{% for blockName in blocks %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.